# Ruby On Rails Not Redirecting On Create

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am creating a website that allows you to schedule events, when creating a new event it is added successfully to the database and the console will output that it's redirected to view the event, however no redirect seems to ever occur. I've tried removing the respond_to do |format| and rewriting it, however that didn't change anything. Neither did rewriting the redirect to redirect_to.

Console output

```
rails_1    |   Event Create (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO `events` (`username`, `date_made`, `date_for`, `title`, `attendees`, `owner_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `description`, `is_all_day`, `color`, `text_color`) VALUES ('screamingatrocks@proton.me', '2022-06-26 21:12:17', '2022-06-08 00:00:00', '', x'', 13, '2022-06-26 21:12:42.625491', '2022-06-26 21:12:42.625491', '', FALSE, '#000000', '#000000')
rails_1    |   ↳ app/controllers/events_controller.rb:30:in `block in create'
rails_1    |   PublicActivity::Activity Create (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO `activities` (`trackable_type`, `trackable_id`, `key`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Event', 35, 'event.create', '2022-06-26 21:12:42', '2022-06-26 21:12:42')
rails_1    |   ↳ app/controllers/events_controller.rb:30:in `block in create'
rails_1    |   TRANSACTION (12.1ms)  COMMIT
rails_1    |   ↳ app/controllers/events_controller.rb:30:in `block in create'
rails_1    | Redirected to https://localhost/events/35
rails_1    | Completed 200 OK in 43ms (ActiveRecord: 15.2ms | Allocations: 5294)
```

Events Controller

```
  # POST /events or /events.json
  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        UserMailer.event_reminder(current_user)
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: "Event was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Form

```
 <%= form_with(model: event) do |form| %>
...
 <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
```

Comment: why do you say that no redirect occurs? It's shown in the log "Redirected to https://localhost/events/35". What are you seeing that leads you to say that no redirect occurs?

Comment: @LesNightingill what I'm saying is that it says it is redirecting but doesn't redirect.

Comment: what are you seeing that leads you to say that no redirect occurs? Your code is fine as is, and the log says its working.

Comment: find where response status `200` is coming from. it should be `302`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using turbo, you need to return status 303 to turbo know that you want to redirect, so you need to add `status: :see_other` to redirect_to

```
format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: "Event was successfully created.", status: :see_other }
```

References:

- https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#redirecting-after-a-form-submission
- https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/why-turbo-breaks-all-302-redirects/79810/3